# How to access pod in k8 cluster via url

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a service running in a cluster in a namespace:

```
NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                     PORT(S)                                                       AGE
amundsen-frontend                       LoadBalancer   10.100.59.220    a563823867e6f11ea82a90a9c116adac-124ae00284b50400.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com   80:31866/TCP                                                  70m
```

And when I run pods:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
amundsen-frontend-595b49d856-mkbjj                    1/1     Running   0          74m
amundsen-metadata-5df6c6c8d8-nrk9f                    1/1     Running   0          74m
amundsen-search-c8b7cd9f6-mspzr                       1/1     Running   0          74m
dsci-amundsen-elasticsearch-client-65f858c656-znjfd   1/1     Running   0          74m
dsci-amundsen-elasticsearch-data-0                    1/1     Running   0          74m
dsci-amundsen-elasticsearch-master-0                  1/1     Running   0          74m
```

I'm not really sure what to do here. How do I access the url? Can I port forward in development? What do I do in production? The front-end pod is one I want to access, so is the search pod.

This is what's in my `charts.yaml` for helm:

```
frontEnd:
  ##
  ## frontEnd.serviceName -- The frontend service name.
  ##
  serviceName: frontend
  ##
  ## frontEnd.imageVersion -- The frontend version of the metadata container.
  ##
  imageVersion: 2.0.0
  ##
  ## frontEnd.servicePort -- The port the frontend service will be exposed on via the loadbalancer.
  ##
  servicePort: 80
```

Comment: It looks like you're already running a `LoadBalancer`-type service, in AWS, so you should be able to reach the AWS ELB listed under `EXTERNAL-IP` and it will forward to your service.

Comment: It timed out and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

With so little information I don't know if I can solve your problem, but will try to help you find it.

To start with it will be helpful if we can see your service and pod config?

```
kubectl get sa amundsen-frontend -o yaml
kubectl get pod amundsen-frontend-595b49d856-mkbjj -o yaml
```

You can try to reach the fronted from another pod, this will help figure out if the problem is in the pod or ingress layer.
To gain shell access inside `search` pod container run:

```
kubectl exec -it amundsen-search-c8b7cd9f6-mspzr  --container <<name of container>>  -- sh
```

*If you have only one container in the pod you can omit the container part from the command above*

Once inside check if your are able to reach `amundsen-frontend-595b49d856-mkbjj` with curl

```
curl amundsen-frontend-595b49d856-mkbjj
curl amundsen-frontend-595b49d856-mkbjj:31866
```

If you are able to establish communication, then look for the problem in the ingress layer. You may want to look at your ingress logs to see why it's timing out.

Network security groups in AWS as also worth exploring.

Is your ingress configured properly?